# Button fill the whole row in TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have a `LinearLayout` in vertical orientation, in the first row I added one button which fills the parent.

I want to implement the same thing using TableLayout.
What I've tried so far is:

[image]

```
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout">
<TableRow 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/firstRow">

<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button" />
</TableRow >
</TableLayout>
```

The `TableRow` fills the parent, but the button inside the row won't fill the whole row.

How to make the button fill the parent like this?

[image]

---

## Edit:

And how to make it vertically fill the parent like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `android:layout_weight="1"`

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Why is doing layouts on Android" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="damn" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

looks like :

[image]

Comment: Yes, use Weight to fix the issue. +1

Comment: @Caffè  I am glad that i could help :) good luck & have fun with android :D btw if my answer helped you please  mark is and correct :) i would be realyy happy :D

Comment: @MatejŠpilár: I have one little question, how about if I want to make `damn` button vertical ?

Comment: @Caffè vertical like how ? that it will take the whole screen below first row ? :)

Comment: @MatejŠpilár: Yes, below the first row but not take the whole scree, only takes one column.

Comment: one column ? try this setting for second button `<Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" ndroid:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="damn" />` ... but i dunno if this is what you are looking for

Comment: then just put it outside table layout to linear layout with vertical orientation ...

Answer (score 1):

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>
```

Comment: It's simple, see to fill the columns use android:layout_weight="1" and then to fill the column just make the height of the button or the TextView height as match_parent, android:layout_height="match_parent". See that simple it is, good luck!!